# Enumerate segments of a module given a module handle

Tags: c++, c, winapi, portable-executable

I want to enumerate all the loaded segments of a module given a module handle. Are there any API functions I can call to do this? Or is the only way reading the PE header and working out which segments are loaded and which are not?

If I have to end up reading the PE header, could someone help describe the structure of the header or link me to a guide and also give steps to enumerate the segments? I know how to do this with an ELF header but not PE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read these MSDN articles by Matt Pietrek and follow their links:

- [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)
- [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)

Comment: The second link helped the most :). It said that `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` structures followed the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` structure and those were exactly what I needed! For anyone else reading this, the number of `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`s following the `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` is specified in `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS::FileHeader.NumberOfSections`